# Calculating Inverse_chi_squared_distribution using boost

Tags: c++, math, boost, statistics

I'm trying to implement a function to calculate inverse_chi_squared_distribution, boost has a container named inverse_chi_squared_distribution, however, when I try to create an instance of the class I get this error `too few template arguments for class template 'inverse_chi_squared_distribution'`.
I'm on wsl:ubuntu-18.04 and other boost functions/containers work fine.

Here's the code generating the error:
`boost::math::inverse_chi_squared_distribution<double> invChi(degValue);`

Not exactly sure how to calculate it even if this instance is created (was gonna just hit and miss till I get it) so help using this to calculate the function would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/inverse_chi_squared_dist.html), you could simply use `inverse_chi_squared my_invchisqr(2, 3);`. Have you included `#include <boost/math/distributions/inverse_chi_squared.hpp>`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, do you want the inverse of a chi-squared distribution (ie its quantile) or do you want the "inverse chi squared distribution" which is a distribution in it's own right, also with an inverse/quantile!

If the former, then assuming `v` degrees of freedom, and probability `p` then this would do it:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp>

double chi_squared_quantile(double v, double p)
{
   return quantile(boost::math::chi_squared(v), p);
}
```

If the latter, then example usages might be:

```
#include <boost/math/distributions/inverse_chi_squared.hpp>

double inverse_chi_squared_quantile(double v, double p)
{
   return quantile(boost::math::inverse_chi_squared(v), p);
}
double inverse_chi_squared_pdf(double v, double x)
{
   return pdf(boost::math::inverse_chi_squared(v), x);
}
double inverse_chi_squared_cdf(double v, double x)
{
   return cdf(boost::math::inverse_chi_squared(v), x);
}
```

There are other options - you can calculate with types other than `double` then you would use `boost::math::inverse_chi_squared_distribution<MyType>` in place of the convenience typedef `inverse_chi_squared`.

Comment: tried this, same error... testing on a remote boost installation to check if my installation is faulty

Comment: @adoDojo Can you share the exact minimal code that is giving you trouble? Test/post it on https://godbolt.org/, so you can find out/show what compilers/flags are involved.